# Input.GetMouseButtonDown() in nested if else block never seems to be true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to check which object (playing piece) the user has clicked on...but the problem is the if else block does not seem to detect the mouse button click. If I remove 'Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)' from the else if condition it works. Here is my code:

```
void Update () {
    if (chance == 1) {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
            if (enableInput == true) {
                enableInput = false;
                markers [0].gameObject.SetActive (true);
                markers [1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                markers [2].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                markers [3].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                a.PlayOneShot (s_Dice);
                DiceRoll ();
                if (subPlayer == 4 && diceno == 6) {
                    Vector3 temp;
                    Vector3 currentPos;
                    subPlayer -= 1;//3
                    temp = transform.position;
                    subplayers1 [0].transform.position = new Vector3 (startingpos1.transform.position.x, -1.8f, startingpos1.transform.position.z);
                    Invoke ("waitandgo",0.5f);
                } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && subPlayer == 3 && diceno == 6) {
                    //print ("clicked");
                    //ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                    //if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                    print("Click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want this to be evaluated every frame the space bar is not pressed, or only the single frame where the player releases the space bar (`Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)`)? In the same way, do you want the else if condition to be true only in the single frame that the mouse button is clicked, or for every frame that the mouse button is held down?

Comment: @Serlite Only the single frame when the mouse button is clicked..sorry maybe i needed to use (Input.GetMouseButtonUp)

Comment: Hmm, can you describe the sequence of input that you envision the user would have to do to get inside that statement? Will it be true as long as they click the mouse while the spacebar is not held down, or only when they release the spacebar at the same time as they click the mouse?

Comment: @Serlite I want the player to be able to click on that gameobject so i can detect it...

Comment: I think I get it - so the order is basically: 1) Press spacebar to roll dice, then 2) If three pieces remain and a roll of 6 is achieved, await a mouse click from the player to choose another piece?

Comment: I've added an answer - let me know if there's anything unclear about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.GetKeyUp()`, `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()`, etc. only stay true for the single frame when the event occurs. In your code, if you're not releasing space in the exact frame you're clicking your mouse button (which will almost always be the case), the two conditions will never be simultaneously met and you'll never enter the `else if` case.

What you want is when space is released, determine if the player's mouse input is required, then start listening for a mouse click starting from that point forward. This way, you're not restricted to a single frame window of releasing space and clicking your mouse at the same time.

You'll need another variable to store whether you're awaiting a mouse click from the player or not - just set the flag to true if you require selection from the player, so any time after the space is released you can click the mouse:

```
bool awaitingPlayingPieceSelection = false;

void Update () {
    if (chance == 1) {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
            if (enableInput == true) {
                enableInput = false;
                markers [0].gameObject.SetActive (true);
                markers [1].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                markers [2].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                markers [3].gameObject.SetActive (false);
                a.PlayOneShot (s_Dice);
                DiceRoll ();
                if (subPlayer == 4 && diceno == 6) {
                    // ...
                } else if (subPlayer == 3 && diceno == 6) {
                    awaitingPlayingPieceSelection = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (awaitingPlayingPieceSelection) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            // Perform your raycast in here for piece selection

            // Only set the variable to false once the player has selected a valid piece
            // If they click something else, keep waiting for input
            awaitingPlayingPieceSelection = false;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I didn't add it here, but you should do some condition checking to make sure you're not moving the game forward without receiving that player input. Make sure you enforce the correct game sequence!*

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It Worked ... Thank You Very Much ...I Really Appreciate It :)

Comment: Glad to help out! Working with input events can be tricky sometimes.